# Integral inequality of Polya

Tags: inequalities, integration

In the book Math Problems AMM (1957), Problem 230, there is the next inequality of D. Polya:

- let $a,b>0$, $0\leq  x \leq a $,
- $f(x)$ --- being not a linear function, and $f(0)=0$, $f(a)=b$, $f(x)\geq 0$, $f''(x)\geq 0$.

Then the next inequality holds true
$$
2\pi \int_0^a f(x)\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2} \,dx  \leq \pi b\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.
$$
($\pi$ of course may be droped on both sides). There is a proof and geometrical interpretation in the above mentioned book. From my point of view the proof is not direct and a bit sophisticated, as it seems.
**Problem 1**. Find a direct proof of this inequality based on some classical inequalities, such as Cauchy-Bunyakovskii, Holder, Jensen, Hardy and so on.
**Problem 2**. Find some generalisations, say in terms of two arbitrary functions, and so on.

Comment: Thank you Daniele, of course it is better now.

Comment: The references to the book are not very precise, which book is it about?

Comment: Reference: The Otto Dunkel Memorial Problem Book, New York, 1957. I have a Russian translation of 1977 by Mir publishing.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3287191/42969

Comment: Dear Martin R  By your reference there is really the same problem, but no solution! All the same thank you.